# Overlay button able to start the video only on clicking center of the video alone but on clicking at any part of the video stop is happening

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(".video")
  .parent()
  .click(function () {
    if ($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused) {
      $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();
      $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
      $("video").attr("controls", true);
    } else {
      $(this).children(".video").get(0).pause();
      $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
      $("video").attr("controls", false);
    }
  });
```

```css
.video {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper{
    display:table;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
}
.playpause {
    background-image:url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2315/default_icon/256/media_play_pause_resume.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    top:0%;
    bottom:0%;
    margin:auto;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <video class="video">
    <source src="http://e14aaeb709f7cde1ae68-a1d0a134a31b545b257b15f8a8ba5726.r70.cf3.rackcdn.com/projects/31432/1427815464209-bf74131a7528d0ea5ce8c0710f530bb5/1280x720.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <div class="playpause"></div>
</div>
```

Video should play on clicking any part of the overlay, but now it is playing only on clicking at the center of the overlay. But pause is working fine as expected as by clicking on any part of the video while it is playing, the video gets paused

Comment: Hold on, I've read your text at least 4 or 5 times and I'm still not sure what you mean. `When I click the play or overlay image on the center alone the video is getting played` So, that's good? `unless if I click somewhere else the overlay image gets faded out` So, that's good too? `but video is not getting played`... so... uh, it should? `on clicking at any part of the playing video the video is paused` and, is that good or bad? Man, can you rephrase the whole things clearly?

Comment: The video should play while I click at any part of the video tag, currently it is playing only if I click at the center.
Kindly look in to the below link
https://codepen.io/thajudeen-kamarudeen/pen/rNzmqJM

Answer (score 0):

What about making the "play" button cover the whole video? Is that what you need?

```js
$(".video")
  .parent()
  .click(function () {
    if ($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused) {
      $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();
      $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
      $("video").attr("controls", true);
    } else {
      $(this).children(".video").get(0).pause();
      $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
      $("video").attr("controls", false);
    }
  });
```

```css
.video {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper{
    display:table;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
}
.playpause {
    background-image:url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2315/default_icon/256/media_play_pause_resume.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    top:0%;
    bottom:0%;
    margin:auto;
    background-size:20%;
    background-position: center;
    border : green dashed 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <video class="video">
    <source src="http://e14aaeb709f7cde1ae68-a1d0a134a31b545b257b15f8a8ba5726.r70.cf3.rackcdn.com/projects/31432/1427815464209-bf74131a7528d0ea5ce8c0710f530bb5/1280x720.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <div class="playpause"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No the image size should be the same but functionality to be changed. Initially if I click on the overlay image the video gets played with no issues and the overlay image is also hided as expected. But if I click on some other place other than center, the overlay image is alone hided but video is not getting played